Reference Request: Hausdorff–Young inequality for the inverse Fourier seires
Let $ \hat f : \mathbb Z^d \to \mathbb C $ denote a function in $\ell^p(\mathbb Z^d)$ where $p \in [1,2]$.
Let $f : \mathbb T^d = (\mathbb R / 2\pi \mathbb Z)^d \to \mathbb C$ denote the inverse Fourier transform/series of $\hat f$.
Let $p'$ satisfy $\frac 1 p + \frac 1 {p'} = 1$.
I am looking for a reference for the inequality $$ || f ||_{L^{p'}(\mathbb T^d) } \le || \hat f ||_{\ell^p(\mathbb Z^d) } .$$
The proof should be an application of the Riesz-Thorin theorem. Does anyone know a proof written down somewhere?

Another reference is Theorem 4.28 of Folland's A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis. CRC Press, New York, 2nd edition, (2015)

The inequality (actually the equality) holds for $p=2$ by the Parseval identity. For $p=1$ the inequality is obvious as if $\widehat{f}\in \ell^1$ then the series $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^d}\widehat{f}(n)e^{2\pi i\langle x,n\rangle}$$ is absolutely convergent and represents a continuous function with Fourier coefficients equal $\widehat{f}(n).$ Hence the sum of the series is equal $f(x).$ Thus $$|f(x)|\le \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^d}|\widehat{f}(n)|$$ i.e. $\|f\|_\infty\le \|\widehat{f}\|_1.$ By application of the Riesz-Thorin theorem we get $\|f\|_{p'}\le \|\widehat{f}\|_p$ for $1\le p\le 2.$
Concerning the references see here. I can recommend E. M. Stein, G. Weiss, Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces, and Y. Katznelson.
